# Does the Shippo API have the capability to suggest address corrections upon validation

Tags: shippo

When doing an address validation, does the Shippo API response have the ability to return address suggestions? For example, in e-commerce sites, when you enter in your shipping address, you sometimes get a popup with multiple address variations that asks which one you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cathy , The address validation doesn't provide address suggestions. It provides info on whether the address is valid or not in the response.

For validating addresses for US and get suggestions, you would want to rely on 3rd party apis something like this : https://www.smarty.com/products/apis/us-street-api or https://www.postgrid.com/lp/address-validation-autocomplete or via UI : https://www.ups.com/address_validator/ or similar tools.

I will create a feature request for my team and see if we can add this as a feature.